# Unity3D WWW get HTML displayed in browser

Tags: unity, javascript, html

I currently have in a web page, on a localhost server, some information that I want to use in Unity. My problem is that this information are stored in some js variables.

I tried to use the WWW class in a coroutine, but I only get the html source code. Is there a way to get the value of this variables inside Unity Editor ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is this page on Unity and browser communication:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html

If you are doing something different you may want to consider wrapping it in a RESTful API. The webpage then returns JSON/XML which you can parse to get your data out.